# `Selected` field is missing from the post request for the product grid mass action

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, massaction, product-grid

I made a custom mass action for the product grid.
This is the ui component part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="barcode">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">barcode</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create Barcode(s)</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="modulename_product_barcode/product/massCreateBarcode"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

In my controller I put this code:

```
    public function execute()
    {
        var_dump($_POST); exit();
...
    }
```

The result of the `var_dump` is:

```
array (size=5)
  'selected' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
  'filters' => 
    array (size=1)
      'placeholder' => string 'true' (length=4)
  'search' => string '' (length=0)
  'namespace' => string 'product_listing' (length=15)
  'form_key' => string 'fgqSDhnd44Eao74Y' (length=16)
```

As you can see the `selected` which contains the product entity ids is present! If I do a search in the product grid after the sku, the result of the `var_dump` is:

```
array (size=5)
  'excluded' => string 'false' (length=5)
  'filters' => 
    array (size=1)
      'placeholder' => string 'true' (length=4)
  'search' => string 'SP' (length=2)
  'namespace' => string 'product_listing' (length=15)
  'form_key' => string 'fgqSDhnd44Eao74Y' (length=16)
```

Here the `selected` is missing. Not sure why ? So how can i get the product entity ids after searching or filtering the product grid for a mass action ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look how the mass delete is done in the core and i saw that i missed some parts.

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
......

/**
* @var Filter
*/
private $filter;
/**
* @var CollectionFactory
*/
private $collectionFactory;
......

public function execute()
{
......
        $productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('selected');
        if (!$productIds) {   //for searching and filters, when the `selected` key is not present
            $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
            $productIds = $collection->getColumnValues('entity_id');

        }
......

}
```

I hope my answer will help someone :) Cheers!